Allure not displaying results
I'm on a Windows machine and trying to populate the dashboard locally. I've installed it using Scoop as recommended by Allure. Some of my system specs:

Windows 11 Enterprise
Edge Browser
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Allure 2.27.0

I've manually created a results folder "allure-result" and placed what should be a working JSON file inside there.
{
 "uuid": "3442196",
 "historyId": "3442196",
 "status": "passed",
 "statusDetails": {},
 "stage": "finished",
 "steps": [],
 "attachments": [],
 "parameters": [],
 "labels": [
   {
    "name": "framework",
    "value": "JUnit"
   },
   {
    "name": "language",
    "value": "Java"
 }
],
 "name": "Basic Test",
 "fullName": "com.example.tests.BasicTest",
 "start": 1683033600000,
 "stop": 1683033615000
}

When I run allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report all seems fine. no error in the CMD. And also, that does not modify my current allure-results folder nor creates another one.
Then running allure serve allure-results the browser launches but the dashboard is empty. There is no error in the browser developer tool, no CORs error or network errors. I've tried using a python instance to host the dashboard and still empty. I've tried explicit paths, launching from within the folders and nothing.

The files inside allure-results should follow the naming convention:

The test result file name should end with -testresult.json
The test container file name should end with -container.json
Test attachments should be stored in files ending with -attachment or -attachment.{ext}


Fantastic! -result.json worked for me. I overlooked that part of the docs. Thanks for pointing that out.
